# Reversing a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, methods, 2d, reverse

I can't seem to create a general method that will reverse a 2D array of any size. I have the following code, which only works for a 3x3 array. Is there a way to modify this code to reverse any size 2D array?

```
I need my array to go from:
[ 1 2 3 ]
[ 4 5 6 ]
[ 7 8 9 ]

to:  
[ 3 2 1 ]
[ 6 5 4 ]
[ 9 8 7 ]
```

But this should work for any array size, not just 3x3 and not just an nxn array (square array).

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int r,r2,c,c2,temp;

    int rows = 3;
    int columns = 3;

    int a[rows][columns]; 

    a[0][0] = 1;
    a[0][1] = 2;
    a[0][2] = 3;

    a[1][0] = 4;
    a[1][1] = 5;
    a[1][2] = 6;

    a[2][0] = 7;
    a[2][1] = 8;
    a[2][2] = 9;

    r = 0;
    r2 = rows-1;

    c = 0;
    c2 = columns-1; 

    while(r<=r2){
        while(c<=c2){
            temp = a[r][c];
            a[r][c] = a[r2][c2];
            a[r2][c2] = temp;

            c++;
            c2--;
        }

        temp = a[r][c];
        a[r][c] = a[r2][c2];
        a[r2][c2] = temp;

        r++;
        r2--;

    }


    for(r=0;r<3;r++){
        for(c=0;c<3;c++){
            printf("%d\n",a[r][c]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I have the following code, which only works for a 3x3 array" -- Are you sure about that? Why does it only work for a 3X3 array, and note that the posted code does not give the claimed output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reversing each row of the array. So write a function that will reverse an array passed as an parameter to it.

The second one would be something like,

```
void swap(int *a, int *b){
     int temp = *a;
     *a = *b;
     *b = temp;
}
void rev(int a[],const int col){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < col/2; i++){
        swap(&a[i],&a[col-i-1]);
    }
}

int main(void){
...

for(size_t i = 0;  i < rows; i++)
   rev(a[i],columns);
...
return 0;
}
```

The problem with your code is that you yourself are contradicting what you want to achieve.

First swap you made is between `r2,c2` and `0,0` This way at first iteration inside the while you are swapping last row and first row. That is what you didn't want to do (atleast the question says so).